# How to transfer File Ownership for a Document which admin doesn't own?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Use Case

- As admin service account, transfer Document Ownership using the Google Docs API, similar to the built in cPanel "Advanced Tools" -> "Document ownership transfer"

Constraints

- APIs are being invoked in context of a Google Apps admin service account rather than the end-user account since APIs are being invoked from Google Apps Script in Sites page
- Authorization is OAuth 1.0 since this is what Apps Script supports

What works:

- Transferring ownership of the admin service account's own files to another user's account as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#updating_sharing_permissions)

What is required:

- Transfer ownership of another user's files, ideally without them sharing any permissions with the admin service account; if there's no other way of doing it, they could share edit permissions on the file with the admin service account.
- Currently this returns a

  " ServiceException - You do not have permission to share these item(s):"

Comment: Please mark this question answered if it is indeed answered.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is possible by impersonating the user using the admin account.  The documentation shows how to do this [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#using_google_apps_administrative_access_to_impersonate_other_domain_users).

Essentially, start by requesting the API URL with `default` replaced with the current owner's email address.  The request must be made while authorized as the admin user, though.

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/user@yourdomain.com/private/full/
```

Once that URL is requested, all feed URLs will be returned with that email already present.  Then, simply change ownership as you would normally.